# Nested Model/Routes in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple blogging functionality in my Rails 3 app. I am trying to add commenting to each post. The `BlogComment` model has a property, `blog_post_id`, to be able to find the corresponding comments for each post. I already setup my associations in the model, I also nested `BlogComments` under `BlogPost` in the routes file.

However, I can't figure out how to give each `BlogPost` access to its respective comments through the controller so that they can be shown later in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've setup BlogPost with `has_many :blog_comments`, and BlogComment with `belongs_to :blog_post`, you can access the post's comments in the post controller with:

```
@blog_post = BlogPost.find(params[:id])
@blog_post_comments = @blog_post.blog_comments
```

Comment: When new comments are created, will I have to set the `blog_post_id` attribute of my Comment model?

Comment: The associations will be handled for you, including setting the foreign keys, if you assign or create the object through the post object.  For example, @blog_post_comments = @blog_post.comments.build gives you a new comment object with the correct ids setup, and if you pass in the comment as a nested resource to the post object, then the new comment will be created with the proper associations as well.  Take a look here for more information: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#building-a-multi-model-form

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to have this as a `comments` association so that you're not re-typing the word `blog` all the time:

```
has_many :comments, :class_name => "BlogComment"
```

This would still let you have your model called `BlogPost` and `BlogComment`, but when you go to  get the comments for a `BlogPost` object:

```
@blog_post.comments
```

No more repetition.

Answer (score 0):

Assumming in your model

BlogPost has many blog_Comments,

In your controller:

@b =  BlogPost.find(1)

in your view

```
@b.blog_Comments.each ....
```